# getting data from edittext placed in listview

Tags: android

I created a list with textview & edittext using holder... it looks like

```
     Textview    Edittext
---------------------------------
     Textview    Edittext
---------------------------------
     Textview    Edittext
---------------------------------
```

but I cant get the data from each every Edittext...
can any one assist me.. how to achieve it... assist with sample code...

Comment: can you provide any accompanying XML?

Comment: Adding more details on code or xml content would help resolve your query faster.

Comment: when u would like to get data from Edittextview? getting data from EditTextView On selecting that item from list? or else....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi try the following code u will reach your requirement,

```
public class TestListView extends Activity {
    ListView listView,listView2;
    String[] titles = {"List 1 title1","List 1 title2","List 1 title3","List 1 title4","List 1 title5","List 1 title6","List 1 title7","List 1 title8","List 1 title9"};

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        listView = new ListView(this);
        listView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        listView.setAdapter(new CustomListAdapetr(this, titles));


        ((LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mailLayout)).addView(listView);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {

                CustomView customView= (CustomView) arg0.getChildAt(arg2);
                TextView textView = (TextView) customView.getChildAt(0);

                Log.v("", ""+textView.getText());
            }
        });

    }
    public class CustomListAdapetr extends BaseAdapter{

        private Context mContext;
        private String[] list;

        public CustomListAdapetr(Context context, String[] titles) {
            mContext = context;
            list = titles;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return list.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return list[position];
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            CustomView cv;
            if (convertView == null) {
                cv = new CustomView(mContext,""+list[position]);
                } 
            else {
                    cv = (CustomView) convertView;

                    cv.setTitle(list[position]);

                    }
            return cv;
        }

    }

    private class CustomView extends LinearLayout {
        public CustomView(Context context, String itemName) {
            super(context);
            this.setOrientation(HORIZONTAL);
            // Here we build the child views in code. They could also have
            // been specified in an XML file.


            mTitle = new TextView(context);
            mTitle.setText(itemName);

            mTitle.setTextSize(25);

            addView(mTitle, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(200, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));


            }
        /**         * Convenience method to set the title of a SpeechView         */
        public void setTitle(String title) {
            mTitle.setText(title);
            }
        /**         * Convenience method to set the dialogue of a SpeechView         */

        private TextView mTitle;

        }

}
```

Comment: thanks... but i can't to this with edittext & onitemclick also fails.. here i used edit text for dynamic process,while click a button all edittext content should transfer to hash table or some thing... can u assist this.... thanks in advance

Answer (score 13):

I had a similar problem, i did as follows;

```
View view = listview.getChildAt(position);
EditText text = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.myEditBox);
String contents = text.getText().toString();
```

Hope it helps!
// Fredrik

Answer (score 6):

```
for (int i = 0; i < telefoneListView.getAdapter().getCount(); i++) {
    View viewTelefone = telefoneListView.getChildAt(i);
    EditText tipoEditText = (EditText) viewTelefone.findViewById(R.id.telefone_form_tipo);
    EditText telefoneEditText = (EditText) viewTelefone.findViewById(R.id.telefone_form_telefone);
    Log.d(TAG, tipoEditText.getText().toString() + ":" + telefoneEditText.getText().toString());
}
```

To navigate into all itens and get EditText on each.

Comment: one of the best answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Through

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

method we can get the click on item position .by using that position we get the appropriate edittext value